# Orden de parametros "$" en mod-rewrite de htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewriterule

No se por que no me funciona esta rule en el htaccess:
Quiero que a la url amigable se le puedan pasar parametros por query string y eso ya lo he logrado.
El problema es que se pueden pasar 2 parametros por querystring (aa y bb), y claro, los pueden pasar en el orden que cada uno quiera, y por ese motivo no puedo definir la posicion exacta de $2 y $3.

Esta es la url que paso por querystring...
http://miweb.com/ferrari-testarossa-auto-id460?aa=rojo&bb=coupe

Esta es la rule que estoy probando pero da error...

```
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9-\+\.]+-id([0-9]{1,5})[\?]?([a-z0-9\-\_]*[\=]?[a-z0-9]*[\.]?[a-z0-9]*)&([a-z0-9\-\_]*[\=]?[a-z0-9]*[\.]?[a-z0-9]*)$ ficha-coche.php?idModelo=$1&$2&$3 [QSA,L]
```

La idea es que pueda pasar como $2 y $3 las duplas completas, es decir, esto "**aa=rojo**" y "**bb=coupe**", asi daria igual el orden en el que me los pasen, pero parece que el rewrite rule solo admite como $2 y $3 los valores "rojo" y "coupe", pero no la dupla entera.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

mil gracias

Comment: ¿Cuáles son las reglas completas del .htaccess que de momento tienes aparte de la RewriteRule que muestras en el ejemplo? Lo digo porque la URL que pasas no coincide con la regla de Rewrite, por lo que no podemos probar sin un ejemplo.

Comment: Si que funciona.... pruebala en https://www.regextester.com/ y veras...  Pero quitale el inicio ^ y final $ de expression claro

Comment: Sí, tienes razón con la regex pero me refiero a nivel de .htaccess, no coincide bien, prueba con https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: ok pruebo y te digo ;)

Comment: no funciona...  yo lo que quiero saber es simplemente como poder pasar parametros por query string a mi url amigable pero sin saber el orden de los mismos... es decir que dé lo mismo pasar `aa=red&bb=coupe` que `bb=coupe&aa=red` , pero que los pueda recoger por $2 y $3 en el htaccess claro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno ya he dado con la solucion.

Esta es la exp regular:

```
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9-\+\.]+-id([0-9]{1,5})?$ ficha-coche.php?idModelo=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Cuando ponemos el flag "**[QSA]**", se pasa toda la querystring (entera) concatenada al parametro $1, asi que ,luego en tu pagina php, puedes obtener cada campo con el tipico $GET["param"]

Ej:  para la llamada con esta url:

```html
http://miweb.com/ferrari-testarossa-auto-id460?bb=coupe&&aa=rojo
```

se obtiene esta url de salida:

```html
http://miweb.com/ficha-coche.php?idModelo=460?bb=coupe&&aa=rojo
```

Era mas sencillo de lo que pretendia hacer.

Gracias a todos por la ayuda